# Why i suddenly can't create rooms anymore?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, photon

Hello i am working with free version of pun 2, 20CCU

i have a game where players can create rooms and do stuff inside the rooms together. everything was working fine.

But one day i was suddenly unabled to create rooms anymore.

when i changed app i was able to create rooms again. so i am wondering if there is a limit of room that you can create per app ?

i read in the link below that there is a limit of 10000 lobbies
Matchmaking Guide | Photon Engine
https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/lobby-and-matchmaking/matchmaking-and-lobby
Global cross platform multiplayer game backend as a service (SaaS, Cloud) for synchronous and asynchronous games and applications. SDKs are available for android, iOS, .NET., Mac OS, Unity 3D, Windows, Unreal Engine, HTML5 and others.

so it might be the cause of my problem. But my questions are what should i do if i release my game and players reach the limit of 10000 lobbies created ? should i create a new app every time the limit is reached ? Does the limit get higher when after switching for 100 CCU plan ? Is there a way to check how many lobbies are created ?

or

Does my problem has nothing to see with the 10000 lobbies limit ?

Comment: why do you create so many lobbies if you only need multiple rooms? and well in general 20CCU means there an only be 20 users connected to our app at the same time .. I see no reason why there should exist more lobbies then there are users ^^

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on Photon forums [here](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/19059/why-i-cannot-create-room-anymore#latest).
The issue is related to webhooks and PlayFab integration.